# Draw a random ticket from container

Tags: c#

I'm doing a raffle where the user enters prizes and sell tickets.Every ticket has a buyer and his name,phone etc.All I have left is to draw a winning ticket and assign the prize to it:

```
 {
    private Random draw = new Random();
    private List<Ticket> ticketContainer = new List<Ticket>();
    private List<Prize> prizes = new List<Prize>();

    public List<Prize> DoDraw()
    {
        int ticketCount = ticketContainer.Count;

        foreach (var prize in prizes)
        {
            int ticketNumber = draw.Next(1, ticketCount + 1);


        }
        return prizes;
        Console.WriteLine(prizes);
    }
```

I have this code , but when I run it nothing happens.Ive been looking and trying to find the answer but been stuck for 2 days and I've triend a few more ways.

Answer (score 0):

Right, so you're drawing a ticket number, and then doing absolutely nothing with the number itself. When the loop re-loops, the value goes out of scope and disappears forever.

From your code I'm assuming that Prize contains some sort of link to the Ticket who won it, so you need to assign it in the loop.

Otherwise its impossible to give a better answer without seeing your Prize class to confirm. (and telling us what exactly you expect to happen)

Answer (score 0):

`List`s are zero-based, which means that for a `List` of `Count` `n`, the indices go from `0` to `n-1`.

Your `ticketNumber` should be `draw.Next(0, ticketCount)` or, alternatively, `draw.Next(ticketCount)`.

However, you also don't do anything with the `ticketNumber` once you've come up with a winning number.

Answer (score 0):

You find an index but don't actually do anything with it.

You could also try to make the draw a separate class and return and remove one random ticket for each `DoDraw`.

```
 class Draw
 {
    private Random draw = new Random();
    private List<Ticket> ticketContainer = new List<Ticket>();
    private List<Prize> prizes = new List<Prize>();

    public Prize DoDraw()
    {
        int ticketCount = ticketContainer.Count;

        int ticketNumber = draw.Next(1, ticketCount + 1);

        var result = prizes[ticketNumber];
        prizes[ticketNumber] = prizes[prizes.Count - 1]; // Put last element in the returned elements place
        prizes.RemoveAt(prizes.Length - 1);
        return result;
    }
```

Making `n` draws would then be a matter of

```
  Draw draw = // create it...
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      var ticket = draw.DoDraw();
      Console.WriteLine(ticket); // Do something appropriate.
  }
```